# copy formula in last column into next blank column in range and pastevalue in the current column

Tags: excel, vba

I searched over the previous questions,those codes work for the last column on the whole sheet, but the problem I am having is I only want the last column in the range, so copy BD to BE and next month BE to BF

[image]

also once copied over, I would like to paste special value on BD, so only leave the formula in the current month column.

The code below always copy the last column on the whole sheet..

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
LastCol = Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(9, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 8).Copy Cells(9, LastCol + 1)
```

Many thanks for all your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Columns.Count` to `"BJ"`  This changes the starting point of the last column from the column furthest to the right on the sheet to column `BJ`, then it goes to the left looking for the first cell with a value.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
LastCol = Cells(9, "BJ").End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(9, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 8).Copy Cells(9, LastCol + 1)
```